# Como seleccionar registros de la fecha mas reciente con MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Tengo la tabla1 con los siguientes registros:

```
campo1    campo2     campo3

Adrian      25       2016-09-17
Juan        27       2016-09-14
Alex        23       2016-09-03
Ana         31       2016-09-17
Rocio       29       2016-09-17
```

En el supuesto caso que el campo3 se este modificando siempre pero no todos los registros al mismo tiempo como puedo obtener solo los registros que se tengan la fecha mas reciente, intente hacerlo con max()

```
Select * from tabla1 where campo3 = max(campo3);
```

En este caso quiero obtener el siguiente resultado:

```
campo1    campo2     campo3

Adrian      25       2016-09-17
Ana         31       2016-09-17
Rocio       29       2016-09-17
```

pero vuelvo a repetir esa fecha no se va a quedar fija siempre se va a modificar por eso intente obtener la fecha mas reciente con max(), ya intente agrupar y nada, si son tan amables de explicarme en que estoy fallando o cual seria la lógica que se aplica

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select * from tabla1
WHERE campo3  = (
    SELECT MAX(campo3)
    FROM tabla1
)
```

Comment: Gracias por responder @Dev. Joel veo que debo usar subconsultas, solo tengo una pequeña duda en el `where` en este caso es un ejemplo con 3 campos y en el `where` comparas los 2 campos de la tabla pero y si hubieran muchos campos, debo comparar todos en el `where` ??

Comment: No era necesario , si se deseaba tener la fecha máxima para algún valor de campo1 y campo2 era necesario el where

Comment: No funciona la consulta amigo, yo quiero obtener todos los registros que tengan la fecha máxima(mas reciente) :/

Comment: eh modificado mi respuesta , verificar :)

Comment: Funciona perfecto amigo, muchas gracias aunque ahora estoy en un dilema otra persona me dio la misma respuesta tuya y se podria decir que al mismo tiempo ahora a quien debo darle la respuesta correcta?? jejeje

Answer (score 3):

La consulta quedaría
de esta forma:

```
SELECT * from tabla1
WHERE campo3  = (
    SELECT MAX (campo3)
    FROM tabla1
)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias funciona de maravilla, se ve tan sencillo pero no se me ocurria hacerlo de esa forma, bueno ahora tengo otro problema a quien darle la respuesta correcta jejeje

Comment: Creo que debe ser a quien la realizo primero, en este caso romarox.

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes varios con el mismo `id` y solo quieres sacar el mayor:

```php
$sql_semaforo = mysqli_query($conection, "SELECT * FROM `citas_pro`WHERE id_cliente= $data[0] AND fecha_proxima = (SELECT MAX(fecha_proxima) FROM `citas_pro` WHERE `id_cliente` = $data[0])");
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [answer]. La pregunta solicitaba una query en MySQL, no en ningún lenguaje invocado desde servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Dada la tabla:

CREATE TABLE `repetidosTimestamp` (
`c1` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c2` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`c3` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`c4` date DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`c1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Con los siguientes datos:

1. Adrian  25  2020-08-01
2. Juan    23  2020-08-01
3. Adrian  22  2020-08-20
4. Pedro   24  2020-08-01
5. Agus    20  2020-08-01

esta expresión:

Select * from repetidosTimestamp as one
WHERE c4  in (SELECT MAX(c4) FROM repetidosTimestamp where one.c2=c2)
order by c4 DESC;

te va a dar esta respuesta:

- 3    Adrian  22  2020-08-20
- 2    Juan    23  2020-08-01
- 4    Pedro   24  2020-08-01
- 5    Agus    20  2020-08-01

que son todos los registros nuevos, limpiandote los registros viejos de la tabla según el campo time.